# Microsoft Graph Explorer App - Permissions issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I've encountered a problem using the graph explorer.
When I try to change the permissions for something with admin consent using my GA account, I get signed out and not back in and the address bar shows the error (not the app itself) - Invalid scope

If i use a native account of that AAD and not my personal Microsoft account that i used to open the subscription and tenant then it works.

Since there is a workaround i don't mind but it is weird the app doesn't show the error and that it won't work for my personal Microsoft account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personal MS account not working may be due to graph explorer using the common v2.0 endpoint.
It means your personal account is signing in as the personal account, not as the external user in your AAD tenant.

Certain scopes do not make sense when used with personal accounts.

A potential workaround is to change the login URL from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common` to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-aad-tenant-id` where *your-aad-tenant-id* should be replaced with the id of your AAD tenant or a verified domain in that tenant.
This will force authentication against that tenant, allowing you to use the external user of your personal MS account in that tenant.

Comment: Thanks but this is a public website and not my own app, i have no control over it.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#

Comment: You have control over the URL in your browser address bar when it takes you to log in :)

Comment: Replaced the common with the Tenant ID in the second logon screen for the modification of permissions and worked! - thanks